# Unable to change Git account

Tags: git, github, window

I tried to push to my repository, but I got the error below:

```
git push origin master
remote: Permission to PhanVanLinh/phanvanlinh.github.io.git denied to edgarphan.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/PhanVanLinh/phanvanlinh.github.io.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

Before, I was using username `edgarphan`, but I have already changed it to `PhanVanLinh`, but it still keeps `edgarphan`.

I have tried to delete the project and clone again, uninstall Git and reinstall, but it won't work.

[image]

#### Global configuration file

[image]

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: what about ```git config --global user.name```

Comment: @unreleased git config --global user.name is `PhanVanLinh` too

Comment: your images are not shown

Answer (score 71, accepted):

This has nothing to do with your `user.name`/`user.email` settings: those are for authorship in a commit. They are *not* used for authentication when you push to a repo.

If Git does *not* ask you for your GitHub (new) username/password, that means [Git for Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases) is using a Git credential helper called "manager" (do a `git config credential.helper` to confirm it)

Meaning: it is caching your old credentials and is reusing them automatically.

In that case, go to the Windows start menu ([image: Windows start]), type "credential" and select the Windows tool "[Windows Credential Manager](https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows/releases/tag/v1.12.0)".
[image]
In it, you will find an entry `git.https://github.com`, which you can edit, and where you can enter your new GitHub username/password.
[image: Enter new credentials]

Then try and push again.

---

With more recent Git version (2.32+, Q2 2021), assuming `<C:\path\to\git>\usr\bin` and `<C:\path\to\git>\mingw64\libexec\git-core` are in your `%PATH%`, you can do the same removal in command-line:

```sh
printf "protocol=https\nhost=github.com\nusername=xxx"| git-credential-manager-core erase
```

Comment: @SeakyLone Than please ask a separate question with more details on your current setup. For instance, if your remote URL is an SSH one instead of an HTTPS one, you would not see anything in the credential manager indeed (since it deals with credentials for HTTPS queries only)

Answer (score 1):

Try to find out the Git configuration file. For a Windows machine it probably located at

`C:\Users\<user_name>\.gitconfig`

This command may open up the configuration file too. Then you can just edit and save:

`git config --global -e`

And after setting the configuration, do:

```
cd /path/to/new/local/repo
git remote add origin https://github.com/PhanVanLinh/phanvanlinh.github.io.git
git push -u origin master
```

Comment: I tried and I received same error like my question.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue where I had not set up the username and password for git and the following solved my issue.

*Note: If you have Enable Two factor authentication for GitHub disable it for a while*

- Step 01

```
Goto Control Panel -> User Accounts -> Credential Manager -> Windows Credentials
```

- Step 02

```
Goto Generic Credentials section -> Add a generic credential
```

- Step 03 - Fill the fields

```
Internet or network address : git.https://github.com
User name                   : your github username
Password                    : your github username
```

And now click on Ok. This will solve the problem of failing to push the repository

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, but it was on a repo I had cloned with SSH.  I had an old `id_rsa` file in `C:\Users\[User]\.ssh` and now Github recommends you use `id_ed25519` but `id_rsa` overrides `id_ed25519`.  So, I had to delete `id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple git accounts and by some reason your git account gets switch , best way inorder to get it corrected would be remove the creds of the git from the windows manager ,

Yes, you are correct in suggesting the use of the Windows Credential Manager to manage Git credentials on a Windows machine. The Credential Manager stores credentials such as usernames and passwords in a secure location, and sometimes it might be necessary to remove or update them, especially when dealing with multiple Git accounts.

Here are the steps you outlined, broken down for clarity:

Access Windows Credential Manager:

Press the Windows key to open the start menu.
Type "credential" and select "Credential Manager" or "Windows Credential Manager."
Review and Remove Git Credentials:

In the Credential Manager, look for entries related to Git.
Remove the credentials associated with the Git account causing the issue. You can do this by clicking on the entry and selecting "Remove" or "Delete."
Git Bash Command Line:

Open Git Bash.
Navigate to your Git repository.
Perform a Git operation that requires authentication, such as git push.
Re-enter Credentials:

Git will prompt you for credentials since the stored ones were removed.
Enter the correct username and password or use another authentication method.
Store Credentials Again:

If you want to store the credentials again, Git will usually prompt you to save them. Alternatively, you can use Git credential helpers or caching mechanisms.
By following these steps, you ensure that Git prompts you for the correct credentials and stores them securely in the Windows Credential Manager. This is particularly useful when managing multiple Git accounts on the same machine.