# Authentication issue with pre-existing Github repo

Tags: git, github, version-control, egit

I'm working on a project with a teammate and he created a GitHub repo to make version control easier. In the past, I've worked with Bitbucket repos, and it was farily easy to set-up. I just used my Bitbucket username and password as credentials and that was it. For GitHub, I managed to set up the repo correctly and can pull from it, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to push. I tried every possible username/password combination and I either get a *git-receive pack not permitted*, or a *Auth failed* error.  What am I missing here? What credentials do I have to use to be able to push? I'm using eGit

Comment: Are you using two-factor authentication?

Comment: @Caleb_McCreary I'm not.

Comment: Would you mind posting a photo of your complete process here? Obviously, do not show any sensitive information.

Comment: Quite simply, I'm right clicking on my remotes, selecting ''change credentials'' and here I've tried putting my GitHub username/password, my userID/password, my GitHub email/password, Git and blank password, and then I try to push my commits and I get error messages, no matter what.

Comment: Well, your github username/password are the ones you would use for authentication, for sure. I've never had an issue where I needed to manually edit my credentials. Typically, if you push from the command line, as long as your repo is linked correctly, it should prompt you to sign in.

Comment: I'm not pushing from the command line though, I'm pushing directly from Eclipse using eGit. Is it possible that the person who created the GitHub repo has to give me some kind of write access or something?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your OS (Windows? Mac? Linux?) and on the URL used.

For instance, for https URL, [Git for Windows would cache credentials in the Windows Credential Manager](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46679813/6309)

For SSH URL, changing credentials would not work at all, since it relies on public/private SSH KEYS in your `%HOME%`(or `$HOME`)`/.ssh`.

Both apply even from Eclipse.