# Git Hub, Trying to push, not letting me enter password, CMD line

Tags: github

I am trying to push pom.xml file to github using CMD

gave my remote url 
then asked my username I did that 
but I cant enter my password, non keys are working 
please help. thank you.

Comment: please show the error, what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an https URL (check what `git remote -v` returns), then maybe your credentials are [cached in the Windows Credential Manager](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46679813/6309).

If you are using an SSH URL, maybe you did not register your public SSH keys (and it defaults to asking for username, although it should ask for password next)

Comment: How to fix? It? Is there way?

Comment: What URL are you using? What does `git remote -v` returns? And what is your `git version`?