# Cant push / pull projects on github

Tags: git, github, intellij-idea

I am currently having problems connecting (pushing / pulling )to my Github account.

I have been using an old github repository prior to this and decided to create a new one. This may have been a main contributor to the problem. Ever since, I cannot push or pull anything anymore.

I have been using Intellij as my IDE. Whenever I push it sends out this message:

"Can't finish GitHub sharing process
                Successfully created project 'practice2' on GitHub, but initial push failed:
                unable to access 'https://github.com/****/practice2.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403"

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vRUXI.png)
So far, the solutions I've tried none have worked.
I have tried to solve it by:

```
- creating the directory in Github and then just pushing it
- committing it entirely
- reinstalling Intellij
- reinstalling git
- tried to change .git config URL
- pushing/pulling it through command line
- deleting and then adding the remote, changing my "global user.name" and "global user.name"
```

none have worked so far

In the command line there seems to be a confusion on which github Im using: remote: Permission to !@#@!/practice.git **(current github im pushing to)**  denied to MEPacana **(old github)**. It has almost been a month since this problem started.

Comment: in your git repo, is your account listed as a collaborator?

Comment: To help narrow down the problem, try pulling from the command line. What happens when you do a `git pull`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double-check the value of the git config credential.helper: it is possible it declares a caching mechanism that keeps proposing the wrong (old) credentials to GitHub.

On Windows, for ,instance, that would be the **[Windows Credential Account](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46679813/6309)**.

Don't forget: changing the `user.name`/`user.email` has nothing to do with authentication.

Comment: It was the Windows Credential Account. I had this problem for almost a month now. I actually made a stack overflow account just to ask this. Thank you!

Comment: @MikePacana Great! Glad to have been of service. Now you can start answering other questions ;)

Answer (score 0):

The language you're using to describe your problem isn't very precise, so I'm not sure what exact problem you're having. I'll try to rephrase your issue, let me know if this is wrong:

> I am currently having problems pushing to or pulling from one of my remote repositories on GitHub.
>
> I have an existing project that has been associated with an old repository on GitHub. I decided to create a new remote repository and since then have not been able to push or pull anything.

If that summary is correct then you may find the [GitHub documentation on changing a remote URL](https://help.github.com/articles/changing-a-remote-s-url/) or the [related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432764/change-the-uri-url-for-a-remote-git-repository) relevant.

As a side point, I recommend using Git from the command line for this problem to isolate out any problems Intellij might be adding. That will also let you follow the directions on those links more closely.

Finally, keep in mind that your remote can use either a SSH or an HTTP URL; worth checking to see if that might be the trouble.