# How resolve error 403 in git?

Tags: github

I have created a blank git repo in my git account and I am trying to push the code from my local machine to it using git bash.
The commands that I have used are :

```
* https://github.com/DevanshiParekh/new-git-project.git
* git push -u origin master
```

I get the following error while doing so :

```
$ git push -u origin master
remote: Permission to DevanshiParekh/new-git-project.git denied to debo-prk.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/DevanshiParekh/new-git-project.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

Here is my config list:

```
user.name=DevanshiParekh
user.email=devanshiparekh63@gmail.com
filter.lfs.smudge=git-lfs smudge -- %f
filter.lfs.process=git-lfs filter-process
filter.lfs.required=true
filter.lfs.clean=git-lfs clean -- %f
color.ui=auto

$ git remote show origin
* remote origin
  Fetch URL: https://github.com/DevanshiParekh/new-git-project.git
  Push  URL: https://github.com/DevanshiParekh/new-git-project.git
  HEAD branch: (unknown)
```

Can someone help me resolve this error?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: can someone explain me where could "denied to **debo-prk**" be coming from ?

Comment: I was just going to ask you that, it really seems strange to me :/(

Comment: what is your login on the local machine?

Comment: yea i guess that must be the issue , but in config and the account i hold no where this name is mentioned

Comment: What do you see when you type `git config user.name` and `git config user.email` ?  Are you sure that your settings are sticking?

Comment: @OznOg its devanshiparekh63@gmail.com

Comment: yes when i do git config user.name and user.email it displays DevanshiParekh and devanshiparekh63@gmail.com only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An https URL should query your GitHub username/password when pushing for the first time (the config `user.name`/`user.email` is irrelevant for authentication)

If it does not, then the wrong credentials are cached in the credential helper.
See the result of `git config credential.helper` to know which one you have.
For instance, on Windows, that would be the [Windows Credential Managers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46679813/6309).

Another cause (for your username/password to not work) would be [if you have activated the 2FA](https://help.github.com/articles/about-two-factor-authentication/). In which case, you would need to use a [PTA (Personnal Access Token)](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-personal-access-token-for-the-command-line/).

Comment: yes there was another account logged in there ...
Thank you so much for helping :)