# remote: Repository not found. fatal: repository

Tags: git, github

My project in github has been moved to another github account. I've added new origin and git repo in my current project. But when I push my new changes to new github repo, I've found following error message. Please let me know how to fix it.

```
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/MyDevelopment/project.mm.git/' not found
```

But I call like `git remote -v` return following accurate results:

```
origin  https://github.com/MyDevelopment/project.mm.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/MyDevelopment/project.mm.git (push)
```

Comment: Are you able to access the repository through a browser?

Comment: yap, sure. I can access that repo through a browser

Comment: There is forward slash getting appended to the repository path, may be that is  causing this.

Answer (score 1):

Double-check the URL (it is case-sensitive)

But also double-check if you have a **[credential helper](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Credential-Storage)** that would have cached your (old account) credentials (username/password) used to authentication you.

```
git config credential.helper
```

For instance, on Windows, that would be the [Windows Credential Managers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46679813/6309).

Answer (score 0):

Reset the url using this

```
git remote set-url origin git://new.url.here
```

It normally causes for the following reasons.

- Check your spelling
- Checking your permissions
- Check your SSH access
- Check that the repository really exists

Check the details [here](https://help.github.com/articles/error-repository-not-found/)

Comment: That is not an ssh URL: that would use the git protocol, which won't work with GitHub since it does not support authentication. It is important for the OP to understand why an https URL does not work.