# IntelliJ Github Issue

Tags: github, intellij-idea

Trying to push a project to github and I'm getting the following Error

```
remote: Permission to RedNetty/RedPractice.git denied to JackCDev.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/RedNetty/RedPractice.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

The issue isn't as simple as me going into Settings > Version Control > Github

I've already changed that but its still trying to push via the wrong account.

Answer (score 4):

Check if you have a git **[credential helper](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Credential-Storage)**active:

```
git config credential.helper
```

For instance, on Windows, that would be the [Windows Credential Managers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46679813/6309).
Open the Windows Credential Store, and see if the first user is registered there: delete that entry, and you will be able to authenticate with the second user.

(Here is an example for BitBucket)

[image: https://kwilson.io/blog/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/4-store.png]

Comment: You fixed it! Thanks a ton.