# Github - Remote repository not found while cloning

Tags: github

I am getting the below error while cloning? How to fix this?

```
$ git clone https://github.com/xxx/yyy.git

Cloning into 'yyy'...

remote: Repository not found.

fatal: repository 'https://github.com/xxx/yyy.git/' not found
```

Answer (score 4):

Either this is the URL of a private repository, and you don't have access.
Or you do have access, but incorrect credentials are stored in a [git credential helper](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials).

or you have copied an URL with lowercase/upercase issues (the URL being case sensitive).

Since it is a private GitHub repo, all you need to do is delete your [cached credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47300337/6309): they will be asked again at the next `git clone`.

Comment: @RamyaMiiM Is it a private repo?

Comment: Yes its a private repo

Comment: @RamyaMiiM Are you the owner of that private repo, or have you been added as a collaborator (https://help.github.com/articles/inviting-collaborators-to-a-personal-repository/)?

Comment: No i am not the owner i am a collaborator ... what shall i do now??

Comment: @RamyaMiiM check your credentials: are you asked to enter your GitHub username/password when cloning?

Comment: @RamyaMiiM That means those credentials are cached. If you are on Windows, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/38553149/6309 and type `git credential-manager delete https://github.com` or do it with the GUI: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47300337/6309 (here showing bitbucket.org, but in your case, look for github.com)

Comment: credential.helper=manager
user.name=ramya007
user.email=ramya.hello@gmail.com ( Here user.email is not correct) how to fix this?????

Comment: @RamyaMiiM Did you fix the configuration? (user.name and user.email are not important here)

Comment: @RamyaMiiM See https://stackoverflow.com/a/47300337/6309: delete the github.com entry. Clone again, this time enter your credentials.

Comment: Thanks a lot :-) now cloning but i have removed credentials instead of "edit" will it make any issue??

Comment: @RamyaMiiM no: next time you enter your credentials, they will be cached again.

Comment: Yeah Thank you :-)

Comment: @RamyaMiiM I meant: https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer (although, as a new user, you might not be able to accept immediately)

Comment: Removed cached credential from system's config - `git config --system --unset credential.helper` and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Generate a Token an GitHub. then Clone your repo by using token code !
using follow that steps

01 : Goto your Github ...  ***Settings / Developer settings*** click ***personal
Access Tokens*** click on **Generate new Token**

02 : Marks the **admin:org**  , **repo** and same required failed .

03 : Must save your **Token link** .that only showe first time.

04 : clone your repo by using ***HTTPS link*** . it work .

05 : if that's not Work. that ***take a pass***  add your Token link that is *your
repo pass*

**if you can't understand  click on img**

[image]