# Git doesn't like my password but github is fine with it?

Tags: git

We have a new corporate password complexity/length policy and ever since changing to that policy I can't use git to talk to GitHub Enterprise from the command line or from the IDEs that depend on the CLI version (such as Visual Studio and NetBeans).  However, I can use GitHub Desktop to do my git tasks just fine.

The CLI and IDE always prompt me for my password, but then reject me with a standard "fatal: Authentication failed for..." message.  Same password in GitHub Desktop works fine.

Our new passwords are 25 characters minimum, is there a limitation on how long of passwords that git CLI supports?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a limitation on how long of passwords that git CLI supports?

No that I know of.

> The CLI and IDE always prompt me for my password, but then reject me.

Check from the CLI:

- if the remote is indeed an https one (`git remote -v`)
- what is the credential helper: `git config credential.helper`: it could have cached the old credentials.

Check and see if 2 factor authentication is turned on.  If so, create a personal access token.  Use that in place of the password.

Comment: It's https.  Credential helper is "manager", which I take it is the window popup I get requesting my username/password when I run git from the command line.

Comment: @BrianKnoblauch Exactly: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/47466980/6309 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/46679813/6309

Comment: No matching entry in the Windows Credential Manager for that repo.  The only thing even remotely git related was for our GitHub API, so removed it, but no change.

Comment: Now, when the popup request your username/password, can you enter it successfully? Or is it rejected?

Comment: @BrianKnoblauch and does your password has any special characters?

Comment: Rejected the same way.  It does have special characters, but nothing I haven't used before and been OK with using git CLI.

Comment: @BrianKnoblauch Still, just for testing, try and percent encode those characters: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#Percent-encoding_reserved_characters

Comment: Strange. The remote url does start with https://... right? (not `git@xxx`). And it does not include a username? (as in https://username@github.com/...)

Comment: Can you make the same git command in the CLI, but first with `set GIT_TRACE=1` and `set GCM_TRACE=1`. Are you behind a proxy? What version of Git are you using?

Comment: Ugh, 2 factor authentication got me...  Apparently that was turned on as well.  I added it to your answer to complete the sequence.