# Git push origin Permission to * denied fatal: Could not read from remote repository

Tags: git, github

So I have my public ssh key added to the git repo. I have the private key added to my /c/Users/totty/.ssh/.

When I run `ssh -vT git@github.com` it says `Hi X! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.`

When I run `git push origin` I get `Permission to * denied  fatal: Could not read from remote repository`

What is wrong with this github? I can't push from cmd, git extensions. But it works from github from windows...

After I remove my ssh keys and run  `ssh -vT git@github.com` I get `debug1: No more authentication methods to try.`.

---

Also another thing that is strange... if you look at the circled text, that's not my username or email anywhere. I even check in my git config and is nowhere. Where is coming from? I mean `gs11118`

[image]

Answer (score 2):

First, the username/email (the one you set with `git config user.name` / `user.email`) has nothing to do with GitHub credentials (a user GitHub account name)

Second, make sure your git push is actually using an SSH URL:

```
cd /path/to/my/local/repo
git remote -v
```

If you see an URL staring with `https://...`, it won't matter that `ssh -T git@github.com` does identifies you correctly: Git would not use that as credentials. It would use what is stored in the [Windows Credentials Manager](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46679813/6309).

Answer (score -1):

You may pushing to a repo that is not belonging to you or owned by you, which is cloned from others.

The repository's URL (which can be shown by `git remote -v`) with SSH format is like this:

```
origin  git@github.com:username/repo.git(fetch)
origin  git@github.com:username/repo.git(push)
```

or HTTPS format:

```
origin  https://github.com/username/repo.git(fetch)
origin  https://github.com/username/repo.git(push)
```

In your repository, you may found that the `username` is not yours, neither your organizations nor your collaborators. Then, if you want to push that, you may come to the original repository (https://github.com/username/repo), to `fork` that repo into your GitHub account (as the question's `github` tag), then use `git remote set-url origin` command to rewrite the local repo's remote URL.

After that, you can push it to the remote, which is owned by you, as a fork to others. **EDIT:** if you are using HTTPS way, you may take a look at [Git Credentials](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials)

Or, if the origin repository is where you are **responsible** for developing, you may request the organization or collaborators to add you as a collaborator.

**EDIT2:** Thanks to the comment (talk?) with @VonC, you may look at the file `~/.ssh/config`, which may be `C:\Users\totty\.ssh\config` due to the image you given, to find whether there is a specified key, an `IdentityFile`, for **this** repo. *Reference*: [Specify an SSH key for git push for a given domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7927750/specify-an-ssh-key-for-git-push-for-a-given-domain)

Comment: No: the remote repo does not matters. What matters (in a red circle in the OP's picture) is the username GitHub uses for authenticating to that remote repository (owned or not): that username is *not* the one expected. My answer indicates where to look for that unexpected username. Once the username used is the right one, then and only then yes: your answer would apply.

Comment: @VonC I tried pushing to other's repository using SSH way, the error is 'Permission to <other>/<repo>.git denied to <me>.', and using HTTPS way will have a more error 'fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/<other>/<repo>.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403'. However the OP doesn't got the error message of HTTPS, and doesn't know who the 'me' ([gs11118](https://github.com/gs11119)) is. Is there any possibility that **this repo** is using gs11118's SSH Key by mistake?

Comment: Possible yes: it really depends on the actual URL used for 'origin'. Regarding ssh, it the remote URL) could refer to an entry in `~/.ssh/config`, which would reference the wrong private key.

Comment: @VonC Thank you. I added my answer with something looks like related.

Comment: This is not an actual answer and the person answering does not seem to fully understand what the problem is.