# Gitea Docker windows - Fatal: Authentication failed

Tags: gitea

I am new to Gitea and Git and thought to install Gitea through docker on a Windows 10 computer to test it out before deploying it elsewhere, but I kind of got stuck right at the end. I can open Gitea inside the browser and create repositories and so on, the problem occurs when I want to execute `git push -u origin master`

The error is :
`remote: invalid credentials
fatal: Authentication failed for ‘http://localhost:3000/user/test.git/’`

This is my docker-compose.yml file (I followed the instructions on the Gitea website) :

```
version: "2"

networks:
  gitea:
    external: false

volumes:
  gitea:
    driver: local

services:
  server:
    image: gitea/gitea:latest
    environment:
      - USER_UID=1000
      - USER_GID=1000
      - DB_TYPE=mysql
      - DB_HOST=db:3306
      - DB_NAME=gitea
      - DB_USER=gitea
      - DB_PASSWD=gitea
    restart: always
    networks:
      - gitea
    volumes:
      #- ./gitea:/data
       - gitea:/data
    ports:
       - "3000:3000"
       - "222:22"
    depends_on:
      - db

  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: always
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=gitea
      - MYSQL_USER=gitea
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=gitea
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=gitea
    networks:
      - gitea
    volumes:
      - ./mysql:/var/lib/mysql
```

Answer (score 1):

I will answer my own question here, it may help someone else with the same problem. I solved it with the help of the answer to this [question on Stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46629838/unable-to-change-git-account/46679813#46679813). The problem was solved after setting the correct username and password in the Windows credential manager.